# Get target name (or icon name) in my code

Tags: iphone

Have been searching for this, I need to have a conditional statement in my objective C code based on the target, but I can't seem to find a direct way to get the target name from the code.

Have been trying to read the icon value from the bundle using:

```
NSLog(@"Icon File: %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"icon"]);
```

which always return null.

Looking for a suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
NSLog(@"Icon File: %@",[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]);
```

That should give you the name that is displayed under the icon.